# Php update specific user specific points

Tags: php, database, save, line

I'm trying to do is update specific data in a user database. in my case is the maxcliks row.
I need it to be updated when the application amount received is greater than the saved value.
He is updating but only when maxcliks is higher than the maxcliks of the best player, thus is not updating when my maxcliks is higher that my maxcliks saved in database.
I need something like this:

`UPDATE users SET maxcliks='$maxcliks' WHERE login='$login' IF maxcliks<'$maxcliks'`

Comment: how do u count the `$maxclicks`?

Comment: Maxcliks is received from a as3 app. He is sending correctly the maxcliks value from flash the problem is update when my pointa came from flash is higher than my points saved in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which DB are you use?

MySQL 5.5.35 does not support your query.

Maybe next query will be helpful:

```
UPDATE users SET maxcliks='$maxcliks' WHERE login = '$login' AND maxcliks < '$maxcliks'
```

Comment: Here is common thing to down vote the answers without any explanation?

What's wrong? My query is performs what is needed

Comment: Now, how can i know if the update was successful? For example, if maxcliks received is higher than saved it saves, and send an echo saying Saved else Not saved??

Comment: @André Piropo, you can use [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) for this

Comment: Thanks, i solved creating a SELECT and comparing received value with saved value.